# why does PGADMIN 4 return more than one name?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

id i the primary key and randomm gives me a random number
since there is only one id from 1 to 6 for every sales person why does pgsql return more than one
here's the code:

select concat(sales_person.first_name,' ',sales_person.last_name) as FULL_NAME
from sales_person
where id=randomm(1,6);

Comment: What does RANDOM(1, 6) do? https://dbfiddle.uk/i7lVuLr2

Answer (score 0):

Postgres evaluates the expression once for every row in the table.  Every time it evaluates the expression, it will get a different random value.  So, it's comparing each row against a different number.  Sometimes, you get 0, Sometimes, you get 1,  Sometimes, you get more.

Moral of the story:  don't use `random` this way.